# DataProtection compatilibity net framework and net core invalid payload exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two projects one using net core the other using net framework.

The share of the dataprotection keys as is explained in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

.netFramework

```
 public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("company")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\keys"))
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
 }

       //hello protected in net framework.
       var helloProtected = MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"),
            "testprotector");
        var base64HelloProtected = Convert.ToBase64String(helloProtected);
```

.netCore

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("company")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\keys"))
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
}
        var bs64msg = //Here i put the protected payload from net framework.
        var msgUnprotected = _provider.CreateProtector("testprotector")
            .Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(bs64msg));
```

And then i get a invalid payload exception.

[Github Repostiroy](https://github.com/Nemeq/DataProtection)

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar problem.